# Why EditText.getText shows null in Android?

Tags: android, string, android-edittext

I have a very strange problem with EditText! I create a form in my app with Edit Texts and I get their content into string value but its empty and shows nothing.

XML code:

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        style="@style/Edittext_form1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/name"/>
```

java code:

```
 private EditText _name;

 public  static  String name;

        _name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        name = _name.getText().toString().trim();

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
```

Comment: You need to show where exactly you are calling this `name = _name.getText().toString().trim();`, if you are calling this in `onCreate()` just after initializing `_name` then it will give null only because nothing is in there.

Comment: Did you set any text to this edittext before getText()?

Comment: Any reason you make `name` static? Also, where are you passing value to `_name`?

Comment: @driftking9987. yes,i write it in * omcreate() * . i though that its works. at the first time i initialize Edittext and String and then i say that get the text from edittext

Comment: @olajide. yes i use _name in another Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Take one EditText, Button and TextView and try this :

---

Main Activity :

```
    btnName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tvName.setText(etName.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

---

activity_main3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".extras.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:hint="Please enter your name"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="Click Here"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/et_name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn_name"
    />
```

Comment: is it possible to getText and check its empty in Button click listener method?

Comment: Yes we can do this, try TextUtils.isEmpty, It will check for empty string and null both,

    `btnName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(etName.getText().toString()){
            tvName.setText(etName.getText().toString());
        }
}});`

Comment: excuse me, is `TextUtils` a string value?

Comment: it is `TextUtils.isEmpty(string)`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is about to get the content of that resource before you set it.

Add this line to your Edittext tag:

```
android:text="some default text"
```

Comment: why should i do this? i need its value that user write down

Comment: Then you should put your code in onClickListener method.